# How to parse style separated paragraphs of MS Word in Aspose or Apache Poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika, aspose, aspose.words

the ms word document has multi-styled paragraphs, normally per paragraphs has one style but you can combine two and more styled text on one paragraph with style separator tool. So how to get child styles and text contets of style separated paragraphs from root parahraph using Aspose Words, Apache Poi or others?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Is this about `Office Open XML` (`*.docx`) or the binary file format `*.doc`? At least in `Office Open XML` (`*.docx`) the style separator only leads to vanish line break for the paragraph. Nevertheless the paragraphs before and after the style separator are two separate paragraphs and can be read as such.

Comment: I've tried apache poi and aspose parser on docx format, but I can get only root paragraph elements and styles. So I'm new parsing document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style separator actually is normal paragraph break but with special attributes set. So you can consider content separated by style separator as two separate paragraphs.

```xml
<w:p w14:paraId="561A87F3" w14:textId="0D47DD82" w:rsidR="00AB32A0" w:rsidRPr="00AB32A0" w:rsidRDefault="00AB32A0" w:rsidP="00AB32A0">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
    <w:rPr>
      <w:vanish />
      <w:specVanish />
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AB32A0">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rStyle w:val="Heading1Char" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Test heading1</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="0982566B" w14:textId="76E92742" w:rsidR="00391656" w:rsidRDefault="00AB32A0" w:rsidP="00AB32A0">
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> test paragraph.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

The following two attributes indicate that the paragraph break is style separator

```xml
<w:rPr>
  <w:vanish />
  <w:specVanish />
</w:rPr>
```

In Aspose.Words you can detect whether paragraph break is style separator by Paragraph.BreakIsStyleSeparator property.

cs:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\test.docx");
foreach (Paragraph para in doc.FirstSection.Body.Paragraphs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Style Name: {0}; Is Style Separator: {1}; Content: {2}", para.ParagraphFormat.StyleName, para.BreakIsStyleSeparator, para.ToString(SaveFormat.Text));
}
```

java:

```java
Document doc = new Document("C:/Temp/test.docx");
for(Paragraph para : doc.getFirstSection().getBody().getParagraphs()){
   String styleName = para.getParagraphFormat().getStyleName();
   boolean isStyleSeparator = para.getBreakIsStyleSeparator();
   String content = para.toString(SaveFormat.TEXT);
}
```

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.

Comment: thanks for reply, I wish success to the whole team :) I've tested on java, but para.BreakIsStyleSeparator never returning true even though there are many separated paragraphs.

Comment: There is an • icon between my separated paragraphs, not ¶ icon, even though combined different styled paragraphs with style separator tool.

Comment: screen shot: prnt.sc/siz5wg

Comment: Dot is a white-space. It seems there are no combined paragraphs in your document, but paragraph with runs that have different formatting. You can loop thorough Run nodes in the paragraph and check their formatting using Run.getFont() property. https://apireference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/run#Font

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved. The issue: the second paragraph has paragrapgh style but because of the first paragraph has character style, the style separator not applying correctly. Cleaned first styled text and created a paragraph styled version, and separated them, that's it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

At least in `Office Open XML` `(*.docx)` using the style separator (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) only leads to vanish line break for the paragraph. Nevertheless the paragraphs before and after the style separator are two separate paragraphs and can be read as such.

Given following `Word` document `WordDocument.docx`:

[image]

The following code reads all paragraphs and gets their styles. There also is a method `getIsLineBreakVanished` which checks whether for  the given paragraph the line break is vanished. This is true for paragraphs in which style separator (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) was used.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordGetParagraphStyles {

 static boolean getIsLineBreakVanished(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  boolean result = false;
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() != null) {
   if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr() != null) {
    if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getVanish() != null && paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().getSpecVanish() != null) {
     result = true;
    }
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));

  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : document.getBodyElements()) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    String style = paragraph.getStyle();
    String styleID = paragraph.getStyleID();
    String text = paragraph.getText();
    boolean hasCRLF = !getIsLineBreakVanished(paragraph);
    System.out.println("Found paragraph:" + " Style=" + styleID + ":" + style + ", Text=" + text + ", has CRLF=" + hasCRLF);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but hasCRLF returning true everytime. There is an • icon between my separated paragraphs, not ¶ icon, even though combined different styled paragraphs with style separator tool.

Comment: @ATES: What that screenshot shows are paragraphs having the paragraph style "Prg". And in two of them the character style part of "Head_5" style is applied to the first text runs. This has nothing to do with your question about style separated paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks @Axel-Richter, deleted the character typed style and created one has paragraph type style, and separated them, solved with your code.